# Linq DbContext.Table.ToList() only returning a first few rows from the sqlite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, linq, .net-6.0

I have an sqlite database attached to a DbContext.

```
private readonly DataContext _context;
```

The connection works fine.

The following queries only returns 4 rows from the database, when then are more than 60 records.

```
var prices = _context.Prices.ToList();
```

How do I get all the rows ? Is there a configuration to be done on the LIMIT on SQLite ?

appsettings.json

```
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "WebApiDatabase": "Data Source=WebApiDatabase.db"
    },
```

The Base Entity

```
     public class BaseEntity
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id {get;set;}
            public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }  
            public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }
            public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        }
```

My Entity

```
    public class Price: BaseEntity
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public List<Commodity> Commodities {get;set;}
        }
```

My database context

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Price> Prices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Commodity> Commodities { get;set;}
    private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

    public DataContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
  
        modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEntity>()
            .Property(e => e.CreatedDate)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("DATE()");

        modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEntity>()
            .Property(e => e.UpdatedDate)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("DATE()");

        modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEntity>()
        .HasQueryFilter(e => !e.IsDeleted);
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Commodity>().ToTable("Commodities");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Price>().ToTable("Prices");

    }
    
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        string connectionString = 
         Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase");
 options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase"));
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified);
    
        foreach (var entity in modifiedEntities)
        {
            entity.Property("UpdatedDate").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
        }

        var deletedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted);

        foreach (var entity in deletedEntities)
        {
            entity.State = EntityState.Modified;
            entity.Property("DeletedAt").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
            entity.Property("IsDeleted").CurrentValue = true;
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();

    }


}
```

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
{
    var services = builder.Services;
    var env = builder.Environment;
    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(
        cfg => cfg.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)
    );
 services.AddScoped<IPriceService,PriceService>();
}

    using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var dataContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();    
        dataContext.Database.Migrate();
    }
```

Comment: Nope, if you didn't configure some command interceptor or some other shenanigans it should not limit your query. There is a common mistake among SQLite developers which is they usually query different database than the connection string in the code.

Comment: I thought the same thing, I also made a ’’copy  always’’ of the sqlite database to the bin folder when in debug mode. The data gets retrieved but why only the first 4 rows ? I also tried ’using context = new DataContext ){}' but does not work. I'm using .NET 6 with entity framework core.

Comment: I just have a baseEntity.    public class BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }  
        public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Are you sure you're opening the correct database file? Where did those 60 rows come from? Any files stored in `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release` are cleared before every rebuild or debug.

Comment: I manually inserted the 60 lines. Then wrote the changes to the database. I did a check with a manual update on the first line. In the code, the context has the updated data at line 1, but only the first 4 rows are fetched.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue.
I did a test with MariaDB, which allowed for sensitive logging feature

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        // connect to sqlite database
        //options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase"));

        var connectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=password;database=WebApiDatabase";

        var serverVersion = new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(10, 11, 5));

                options.UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion)
                //Change or removed for production.
                .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        
    }
```

In the terminal I saw that the following SQL was generated from

```
_context.Prices.ToList()

   Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT `b`.`Id`, `b`.`CreatedDate`, `b`.`DeletedAt`, `b`.`IsDeleted`, `b`.`UpdatedDate`, `a`.`Name`
      FROM `BaseEntity` AS `b`
      INNER JOIN `Prices` AS `a` ON `b`.`Id` = `a`.`Id`
      WHERE NOT (`b`.`IsDeleted`)
```

The table BaseEntity was used in the join. That was why I was getting  0 rows.
So before inserting data manually through SQL in this scenario, the table BaseEntity should first be populated with an Id to match the id in the target entity ( Prices in my case)